# Using PHP to Search and Replace POST vars in docx document

Tags: php, str-replace, docx

I am trying to do a search and replace on a Microsoft Word docx document.  The odd problem I am having is that, of the 7 posted vars, 1 and 5 do not replace.  In checking Chrome Tools, they all appear in the posted form data.  The names are all spelled correctly too.

To explain this code, I am opening a template doc, copying it to another name (the named file which will be downloaded), replacing text in document.xml, then replacing text in the footer.  Then I close the file and download it.  It downloads, except, the vars $pname and $hca2name do not replace inside of the document.  All other vars are properly replaced.

Any thoughts are very much appreciated.  Thank you.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
$pname = (string) $_POST['pname'];
$countyres = (string) $_POST['countyres'];
$a1name = (string) $_POST['a1name'];
$a2name = (string) $_POST['a2name'];
$hca1name = (string) $_POST['hca1name'];
$hca2name = (string) $_POST['hca2name'];
$atty = (string) $_POST['atty'];
$countyres = (string) $_POST['countyres'];
$fn = 'POA-'.$pname.'.docx';
$s = "docs_archive/PA-poas2no.docx";
$wordDoc = "POA-".$pname.".docx";
copy($s, $wordDoc);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
//This is the main document in a .docx file.
$fileToModify = 'word/document.xml';
if ($zip->open($wordDoc) === TRUE) {
    //Read contents into memory
    $oldContents = $zip->getFromName($fileToModify);
    //Modify contents:
    $newContents = str_replace('{pname}', $pname, $oldContents);
    $newContents = str_replace('{a1name}', $a1name, $newContents);
    $newContents = str_replace('{a2name}', $a2name, $newContents);
    $newContents = str_replace('{hca1name}', $hca1name, $newContents);
    $newContents = str_replace('{hca2name}', $hca2name, $newContents);
    $newContents = str_replace('{atty}', $atty, $newContents);
    $newContents = str_replace('{countyres}', $countyres, $newContents);
    //Delete the old...
    $zip->deleteName($fileToModify);
    //Write the new...
    $zip->addFromString($fileToModify, $newContents);
    //Open Footer and change vars there
    $ft = 'word/footer1.xml';
    $oldft = $zip->getFromName($ft);
    $newft = str_replace('{pname}', $pname, $oldft);
    $zip->deleteName($ft);
    $zip->addFromString($ft, $newft);
    $zip->close();
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header('Content-Type: application/msword');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fn.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
readfile($fn);
unlink($fn);
exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: First, make sure that `var_dump($_POST)` has everything you need. Then, make sure that your original document has the strings you are looking to replace.

Comment: I did.  Here is that result.  Seems like it should be correct    array (size=7)
  'pname' => string 'Freddy Foobar' (length=13)
  'a1name' => string 'Betty Boop' (length=10)
  'a2name' => string 'Allen Wrench' (length=12)
  'hca1name' => string 'Betty Boop' (length=10)
  'hca2name' => string 'Allen Wrench' (length=12)
  'atty' => string 'Charlie Brown' (length=13)
  'countyres' => string 'Beaver' (length=6)

Comment: If Anyone knows, the problem appears to be within somehow breaking up the text I entered:

Comment: Hi there - Can perhaps rewrite a working code? Also, am confused on how to save as a new file.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of any future reader experiencing a similar problem, when I analyzed the document.xml file within the zipped docx file, my variable names were often not contiguous  instead of {pname}  it would be seperated into {    pname

Open you main document template, got to File, Inspect Document, Check for issues.  This will allow you to clean up the file and remove much of that intervening xml which, I assume, is some document tracking data.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes check your document.xml and footer1.xml file.Your fields should be continuous but I have one issue with your code when file download it is not open in word showing some error.